# Picture folder became a duplicate of document folder

Tags: windows-10

Im having problem exactly like in this [post](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/picture-folder-became-a-copy-of-document-folder/a25c76c2-191a-40fc-8ab5-94214519fc8a) but unfortunatly the answer does not solve my problem.

Another clue is that under *users/myname/* there is no picture folder anymore

The picture folder pointing to the document folder under *users/myname/documents* but moving the location of the pictures would also move the location of the of the documents folder so thats a dead end. Both of them restores to default at *users/myname/documents*

Comment: It is not likely a true copy - not on any of my computers, but it IS a pointer to the true document file.  You might try clearing the Quick Access folder (Right click on Quick Access, Properties, Options, Clear) . Close out and restart and see if that makes your folders display correctly

Comment: @John Quick Access has no properties on right click, i kinda disabled it quite some time ago, but i know where else i can find what you mean, i cleared it and restarted unfortunately no success

Comment: Sorry, I meant click directly on Options.  Since no success, open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator and run:  dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth  and then follow with SFC /SCANNOW  . Restart when done and test.  If this fails, you will need to do a Repair Install from the Windows 10 Media Creation Link

Comment: @John unfortunately it did not work, im downloading the windows iso currently, in the meantime do you know a way to delete/add a subcategory of this pc? like customize the subcategories?

Comment: Repair Install should fix your issue. Please keep us posted

Comment: @john unfortunately no success.

Comment: If Repair Install does not work, you need to back up your data and reinstall Windows. Unfortunately, that is the only next step past Repair Install.

Comment: Ill try asking in the windows forum for a more recent solution and if all that fails then i will give up and reformat the :(

Comment: Generally that kind of error is pervasive OS damage or Windows User Profile damage, neither of which are easy to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Thread was answered in this [post](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files/my-photos-folder-became-a-copy-of-document-folder/b9a32a02-8fe9-438d-ac62-60225ed7e731?tm=1581798430558&page=2) in the microsoft community via register editing.

Note to save a copy of the registry before touching anything.